# Understanding TypeScript decorators

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to create a simple `@enumerable` decorator just like the example in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). But cannot get it to work. Am I missing something?

Decorator

```
export function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.enumerable = value;
    };
}
```

Class

```
export class MyClass {

    @enumerable(true)
    get getter():string {
        return 'value';
    }

}
```

Test

```
var cls = new MyClass();
console.log(cls.propertyIsEnumerable('getter')); // returns false, expected true
console.log(Object.keys(cls));                   // returns [], expected ["getter"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(cls));                // returns {}, expected {"getter":"value"}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // "target": "ES2015",
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    }
}
```

Comment: why did I get -1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator makes the `getter` enumerable in the prototype and not the instance.

With your code try:

```
console.log(MyClass.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable('getter')); // true
console.log(Object.keys(MyClass.prototype)); // ["getter"]
console.log(JSON.stringify(MyClass.prototype));  // {"getter":"value"}
```

But if you use for/in loop on the instance you'll get it:

```
for (let item in cls) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

Prints: `getter`.
The reason for this is that [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the
>   same order as that provided by a for...in loop (**the difference being
>   that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as
>   well**)

---

#### Edit

It will be easy to control how your stringify instances if you introduce a `toJson()` method, for example:

```
class MyClass {
    private x: number = 4;
    private str: string = "str";

    get getter(): string {
        return 'value';
    }

    toJson(): string {
        return JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this, { "getter": this.getter }));
    }
}

var cls = new MyClass();
console.log(cls.toJson()); // "{"x":4,"str":"str","getter":"value"}"
```

Comment: Thanks @NitzanTomer. But that's strange to me. The goal is to get the `getter` property when JSON stringified. Is it possible with an enumerable decorator?

Comment: Not easily. Check my revised answer